# Image segmentation on MATLAB with Alexnet/Googlenet etc

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I try to segment image by using Deep learning on MATLAB. I have read this article https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/alexnet.html
However, this guideline is only for a given images with labels are in the path (folder name).

I want to do something like that: I have two images folders - orignal images and the label images (segmented images). How can I use with alexnet or googlenet in this case?

Sorry I have no code here because I still cannot imagine how to do :(
Anyone have experience to do this task, please write out the guide!

Here is my example - but error, cannot run:

```
clc;
clearvars;
close all;

dataSetDir = fullfile('C:\Data');
imageDir=fullfile(dataSetDir, 'orinals');
labelDir=fullfile(dataSetDir,'labels');

imds=imageDatastore(imageDir);
imdsl=imageDatastore(labelDir);

classNames=["skin","background"];
labelIDs=[1 0];
pxds=pixelLabelDatastore(labelDir,classNames,labelIDs);
I=read(imds);
C=read(pxds);
I=imresize(I,5);
L=imresize(uint8(C),5);

alnet = alexnet;
layers = alnet.Layers;
opts = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MiniBatchSize',10, ...
    'MaxEpochs',6, ...
    'Shuffle','every-epoch', ...
    'InitialLearnRate',1e-4, ...
    'ValidationFrequency',3, ...
    'Verbose',false, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');

trainingData=pixelLabelImageSource(imds,pxds);
tbl=countEachLabel(trainingData);
totalNumberOfPixels=sum(tbl.PixelCount);
frequency=tbl.PixelCount/totalNumberOfPixels;
classWeights=1./frequency;
layers(end)=pixelClassificationLayer('ClassNames',tbl.Name,'ClassWeights',classWeights);

net=trainNetwork(trainingData,layers,opts);
save skincnn.mat;
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to cut images? According to what criteria?

Comment: You should read this paper: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf for ideas on how to use a pre-trained network in the context of a semantic segmentation problem. An implementation based on vgg16 is in the Computer Vision toolbox: https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/fcnlayers.html. To start with, you are going to want an encoder/decoder structure to your network. http://blog.qure.ai/notes/semantic-segmentation-deep-learning-review